# Adding data to scatter chart each with their with own x-axis range

Tags: excel, charts, unique-constraint, vba

Before adding the line that sets the x-axis range for the series any combination of files could be selected and plotted. With that line (' * * * * at the end) if a file that is already on the plot is selected in the next set of files to plot, as other than the first file in the new group, an error occurs. If that line is commented the problem goes away. Without each series having their own x-axis values some data doesn't plot properly (have an example csv file of that also). The files being plotted are 170kB csv files. The worksheet and files can be provided.

```
Sub GetDataAndDisplayChart()
  Dim vFile, vFiles
  Dim iFirst As Integer
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim rXValues As Range
  Dim rYValues As Range
  Dim iSer As Integer
  Dim WkShName As String
  Dim StartWkShCnt As Integer
  StartWkShCnt = Worksheets.Count
  ' get a set of CSV files to chart
  vFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename("csv files (*.csv), *.csv", , "Select files to chart", , True)
  If TypeName(vFiles) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  iFirst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count + 1
  ' import each selected CSV file to a new sheet in this workbook
  For Each vFile In vFiles
    Workbooks.OpenText vFile, xlWindows, DataType:=xlDelimited, comma:=True
    ' move the sheet into this workbook
    ActiveSheet.Move after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
  Next
  Worksheets(iFirst).Select
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  ' confirm the range to plot
  Set rXValues = Range("$A$3:$A$10002")
  Set rYValues = Range("$B$3:$B$10002")
  Worksheets("Chart").Select
  With Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    ' add the first set of data to the existing chart (can have problems if you delete the old data first)
    .SeriesCollection.Add Union(rXValues, rYValues), serieslabels:=True, categorylabels:=True, Replace:=True
    .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.Count).Name = Worksheets(iFirst).Range("A1")
    ' delete the old curves that were already on the chart
    For iSer = .SeriesCollection.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
      .SeriesCollection(iSer).Delete
    Next
    ' add the new data from the addtional files
    For iSer = iFirst + 1 To Worksheets.Count
      .SeriesCollection.Add Worksheets(iSer).Range(rYValues.Address)
      WkShName = Worksheets(iSer).Name
      .SeriesCollection(iSer - StartWkShCnt).XValues = "= " & WkShName & "!" & rXValues.Address   '****
      .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.Count).Name = Worksheets(iSer).Range("A1")
    Next
  End With
  ' delete the older worksheets that were already here
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  For iSer = iFirst - 1 To 1 Step -1
    If Worksheets(iSer).Name <> "Chart" Then Worksheets(iSer).Delete
  Next
End Sub
```